# Linux rpm -Uvh (error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/__db.000)?

Tags: linux

[image]

My problem is: `rpm -Uvh oracleasm-support-2.1.7-1.el5.x86_64.rpm`

It gives me this error:

```
(error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/__db.000)
```

How can I fix it? I think my database is corrupted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You know that updating of packages is a duty of the system administrator, also called `root`? Only `root` is allowed to change the RPM database in any way.